# Is there a way to list all the textboxs, comboboxs, labels from a form that has multipages in a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, controls

Hi Stackoverflow community, I was wondering if there is a method to list all the controls (Labels, Textbox, ComboBox) from a form with multipage? This is because I need to update the script but it has around 30 pages and approximately 200 controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be Ok with Pages
I put it into a module then from anywhere in the form you call it with

```
ListAllMyControls Me, ""
```

Worked for me - I think - My form also had lots of pages and lots of controls - I didn't run a thorough check but this lists objects with a multi-level hierarchy like

```
Userform1.MultiPage1.Page1.Label1
Userform1.MultiPage1.Page1.TextBox1
Userform1.MultiPage1.Page2.Label1
Userform1.MultiPage1.Page2.TextBox1
```

The main routine follows

```
Public Sub ListAllMyControls(SrcObj As Object, dParentNames As String)
   Dim dCtr As Long, xObj As Object, ParentsWere As String, ParentsB4 As String
   
   ' List this Control
   ParentsWere = dParentNames
   dParentNames = IIf(dParentNames = "", "", dParentNames & ".") & SrcObj.Name
   Debug.Print dParentNames
   
   dCtr = 0
   On Error Resume Next
   dCtr = SrcObj.Controls.Count
   On Error GoTo 0
   
   If UCase(Left(SrcObj.Name, 9)) = "MULTIPAGE" Then
      For Each xObj In SrcObj.Pages
         ParentsB4 = dParentNames
         ListAllMyControls xObj, dParentNames
         dParentNames = ParentsB4
      Next xObj
   Else
      If dCtr > 0 Then
         ' List all my controls
         For Each xObj In SrcObj.Controls
            ParentsB4 = dParentNames
            ListAllMyControls xObj, dParentNames
            dParentNames = ParentsB4
         Next xObj
      Else
         dParentNames = ParentsWere
      End If
   End If  ' MultiPage
End Sub
```

Added comment - Problem is this seems to list objects twice when they're in a page. It lists them as Controls of the page and also as controls of the form the page is ultimately on.

Comment: I tried putting the Public Sub ListAllMyControls in a module and the ListAllMyControls Me, "" in the script from the form. But the following error appears: "Run-tiem error '1004' Application-defined or object .defined error. :(

Comment: @Andres What line does it crash at and what version of Excel are you running ?   I just copied the code from my answer and pasted it into a different workbook with a different form and it ran fine

Comment: Burn I have this version: (Microsoft Excel 365 (2016) 32-bit) and the error is a Run-time error doesn't show me any line to solve

Comment: Have you  locked VBA project ? If so unlock it

Comment: I'm the owner I don't have any password for the VBA project. Do I have to do any changes in the code before running the macro?

Comment: No, Just copy that 1 routine and paste it into your project (as you did) then add the calling 1 liner to a button or something clickable on your form

Comment: You could also try compiling the code from within the VBA project and see if that identifies a problem line.  Also I didn't have Option Explicit so if you added it to a module that did have that might be the cause .... even then I expect Excel to highlight the problem

Comment: Thank you, I believe that I have a problem with the form because I ran the macro in another form and I work perfectly my friend.

Comment: Great, glad I could help - enjoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224942/discussion-between-andres-diego-menendez-and-tin-bum).

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code to the form's code sheet and link it to a button you might temporarily add for this purpose.

```
Private Sub GetControlNames()
    
    Dim Ctl As Object
    
    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        Debug.Print Ctl.Name, Ctl.Parent.Name
    Next Ctl
End Sub
```

At the click of the button all control names will be listed in the Immediate Pane. In my test the `Parent.Name` was the form's name but my hope is that it will show the page the control is on in your setup. You might then replace `Me.Controls` with `Me.Controls([Page Name]).Controls` and get the names of the controls on any page of your project. This idea may need a little tweaking because I didn't try it.